# BrowserManager Returns null - Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am strugling with the Flex 4 - BrowserManager, somehow it works when you execute the code from the bin-debug folder, but when I export a release build then it does not work.

This is the code:

```
var bm : IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();                
bm.init();
var o : Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(bm.fragment, "&");
```

I am trying to use it to get external parameters into the swf file, but it simply does not work when I export a release build.

This blog http://flexperiential.com/2010/05/06/browsermanager-returns-null/ knows there is something wrong with this BrowserManager, but the solution they suggest does not work, they make some sort of weird trick that you can not reproduce in your project.

If someone could give me some help here, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. In fact, the BrowserManager works from the bin-debug folder wherever it's located in your hard drive, and when you "Export a release build" it wont work from your hard drive **unless you place the bin-release folder in the Flex 4 project folder, which is usually at this address "C:\Documents and Settings\your-user-name\Adobe Flash Builder 4"**; yes, I know it sounds weird, but this is how it actually works.

So, if you find this problem, just copy the bin-release folder to this location and double-click the html file to load again the flex project in your browser.

I also had this problem on my remote server (the **BrowserManager** was not working either), and was because I forgot to upload the **history** folder which is also located inside the bin-release folder, so don't forget to upload this folder too.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue. In my case, use of history.js was commented in index.template.html file. Uncommenting it worked for me.